# If any text within a range matches text within a cell, output matching text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I need to see if any text in the range C1:D3 matches any text in A1.  If it does, output that text to B1.  If it doesn't, output nothing in B1.

Using the data from the list below, I've successfully used this array formula when the lookup range is in one column C1:C3, but can't get it to work when spreading the lookup across two columns from C1:D3.

**This worked when searching across one column: Column C**

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$3,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$C$1:$C$3&"*"),0)),"")}
```

**Changed it it this to search across two columns - didn't work: Columns C & D**

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$D$3,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$C$1:$D$3&"*"),0)),"")}
```

**Data**

- C1,2,3 contains:  new york, los angeles, san diego
- D1,2,3 contains:  toronto, jacksonville, nyc
- A1,2,3,4,5,6 contains:  birth certificates new york, los angeles death certificates, marriage certificates, san diego divorce certificates, marriage certificates, divorce jacksonville
- B1 contains the formula, then drag it down through to B6

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by nesting your [IFERROR functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) to pass the lookup into the second column if the first does not produce a match but I suspect that your sample data does not adequately describe the scope of C1:D3. For your sample data this would be accomplished with the following *array formula* in B1.

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$3,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$C$1:$C$3&"*"),0)),IFERROR(INDEX($D$1:$D$3,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$D$1:$D$3&"*"),0)),""))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. once entered correctly you can fill down as necessary.

[image: Two column lookup with IFERROR]

If the scope of C1:D3 is significantly different from you've described, other methods may be more appropriate; including transposing the lookup to a horizontal one if you actually had more columns than rows.

Comment: Hello Jeeped, thank you for this answer!  Yes, the data set is larger.  I used a smaller sample to make it easier to propose the question and the answer.  Currently there are 15 columns (and growing) and over 3,000 rows depending upon the column.  With your solution we would end up with a large number of nested iferror functions and as soon as you add more columns you'd have to add more nested iferror functions?

Comment: Yes, I would suppose that 15 columns × 3000+ rows may be *significantly different* than the 2 columns × 3 rows sample you posted. This would make my suggested solution wholly irrelevant as any proposed array formula solution involving a reverse wildcard would be. You are probably better off with a VBA sub procedure that can be run on-demand rather than any live worksheet on-calculate alternative.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped.  Didn't mean to mislead.  Sorry for any miscommunication.  How would you do the VBA sub procedure that you mention?

Comment: I see your biggest problem as being the *reverse wildcard*. Instead of using *find this as part of that* you want to reverse it as *find an undetermined portion of this in all of that*. That simple flip of wildcarding the target instead of the source makes calculation a mess. You are almost better to repeatedly search for every known combination of the words within the source as wildcarding the target.

Comment: Sounds compelling.  How would you accomplish this?

Comment: Could this formula be modified to accomplish the task?

{=INDIRECT("R"&REPLACE(TEXT(MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,$C$1:$D$3)),(ROW($C$1:$D$3)+0)*1000+COLUMN($C$1:$D$3))),"000000"),4,0,"C"),FALSE)}

....it currently only works if A1 exactly matches the text string in one cell of the range.

Comment: No, an INDIRECT is not going to really help. Particularly as it is a volatile formula that recalculates whenever anything in the workbook changes.

Comment: Is there any other formula that would be better?

Comment: Actually a worksheet redesign should be considered but there isn't anywhere near enough information to start making recommendations in that area. A UDF could be written to reduce the inefficiency but you are still trying to match *'123 abc 321'* in 30 columns that *may* contain *'abc'*. I also strongly suspect that your sample data is not actually representative of your actual data.